# Wave Function Integral I need help conceptually and Mathematically

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, hilbert-space

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\partial^2\bar{\psi}}{\partial{x^2}}\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial{x}}~dx.$$

I have read that this is equal to Zero. Only problem is that what I am reading about doesn't really explain why.

I think it is that at positive and negative infinity the $\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial{x}}$ approaches 0. I am thinking about the Gaussian when I think about this, but then how do I show it mathematically, as well.

A note I tried to search this online, but it s hard to find anything on my specific problem and I am not sure what it is I need to search to get the result I need.

Comment: Maybe this will clear things up: Why don't you try to first integrate by parts and then see what condition you end up with for this integral to vanish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you suppose that $\psi$ is a real function, then as suggested by @Danu:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{\partial^2{\psi^*}}{\partial x^2}\dfrac{\partial{\psi}}{\partial x}\, \rm{d}x = -\int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{\partial{\psi^*}}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial^2{\psi}}{\partial x^2}\, \rm{d}x,$$

and this gives zero, since $\psi=\psi^*$ and we always suppose that the function goes to zero smoothly at infinity.

However, if you consider for example $\psi(x)=\left(\frac{1}{{\pi}}\right)^{1/4}e^{-x^2/2+i x}$, we obtain after some work

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{\partial^2{\psi^*}}{\partial x^2}\dfrac{\partial{\psi}}{\partial x}\, \rm{d}x= - \frac{5i }{ 2},$$
which is different from zero.

**In conclusion:** This expression gives a vanishing result only for *real wave-functions* or functions with a *global* complex phase. If you have a function with a complex *local* phase, this result does not stand anymore.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "global complex phase" and "complex local phase". Please elaborate.

Comment: @LDC3 If $\psi(x)= e^{i \alpha} \phi(x)$, where $\phi(x)$ is real and $\alpha$ is a **real number**, then we can say that we have a **global phase** and the result is true. As you probably know, wave-functions are defined up to a global phase.

But in the general case, it is not true that this gives zero. To show that, I have constructed a counterexample with a function $\psi(x)=\phi(x) e^{i\alpha(x)}$, where $\alpha(x)$ is a real function which depends on the point $x$ (this is the meaning of **local**).